# Iterate TObjectList

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, loops, visitor-pattern, tobjectlist

i have ObjectList container and i want to add an internal 
iterator (Visitor Pattern) in fact i'm attempting to determine
duplicates in my List..

a sample: http://pastebin.com/pjeWq2uN

this code to provide an insight of what i'm trying to achieve..

```
TFindDuplicatesMethod = procedure(s1, s2: string) of object;

TPersonList = class(TObjectList)
public
  procedure Iterate(pMethode: TFindDuplicatesMethod)
end;

procedure TPersonList.Iterate(pMethode: TFindDuplicatesMethod)
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
  pMethode(TMyClass(Items[i]).S1, {But i don't have the second parameter because
                               it comes from outside of PersonList Ex: OpenDialog.Files[i]})
end;

function FindDuplicate(S1, S2: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if S1 = S2 then
  Result := True;
end;

begin
  Files.Iterate(FindDuplicates(S1, S2));
end;
```

i'm wondering how OOP solve such problem.

thank's in advance...

Comment: i'm working on delphi 2010 David

Comment: A simple iterator has nothing to do with the Visitor Pattern.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thamk's my oop skills is worse just like my english so please if you could give me some example i will be thankful for your help..

Comment: @UweRaabe yes you're right i just follow tuto from [link](http://tiopf.sourceforge.net/Doc/Concepts/2_TheVisitorFramework.shtml)

Comment: First of all you need to re-write the code to use the generic containers in Generics.Collections. That allows you to stop casting everywhere.

Comment: The basic premise of this question is wrong. You can't use a single iteration to find duplicates. Duplicate finding requires double iteration, and carefully orchestrated. Your proposed solution is wrong. Please tell us what your underlying goal is and let us tell you how to solve the problem.

Comment: ok i will prepare sample...

Comment: In fact, you are not even finding duplicates. Duplicates are when the list contains multiple items that match. For example a string list that contained two elements with the same string. You want a method named `IndexOf`, or `Contains`. Those methods exist already in `TList<T>` the generic container.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but I've given up. The question is too broad as it stands.

Comment: @David don't given up the question is about iterate the ObjectList and Check for duplicates that's all...

Comment: @S.FATEH I'm hesitant to write this because it's not directly related to your question and I risk downvotes. Just a quick note that the three lines in your FindDuplicate function could be replaced by one line: Result := (S2 = S1);  Your FindDuplicate code works fine as is, but the single line is a bit more readable in my opinion.  (The parentheses are not necessary, but help to make the single line more readable.)

Comment: @S.FATEH The code you wrote won't check for duplicates. It performs linear search. I honestly have no idea what you are trying to do. I know English isn't your first language, but your English is actually fine. You need to slow down a bit and describe your problem. Don't tell us about your proposed solution. Tell us about the problem. We can tell you how to solve it.,

Comment: @David i do my best to find the problem 
and to solve it but i always come to dead end 
that's why i post my question please take a look at 
http://pastebin.com/pjeWq2uN and forget about adding
internal iterate...

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer a question based on an off-site pastebin. Perhaps someone else will. In my opinion you aren't trying hard enough to ask a good question. I'm sorry if that sounds harsh. You need to completely re-write your question so that we can understand it.

Comment: I agree with @DavidHeffernan - the problem isn't clear.  You have a TObjectList and you want to find duplicate entries; that much we can gather.  The question in my mind is what you want to do when you find them.  Even if the above code were implemented to work it wouldn't do anything - the boolean value which would flag a duplicate is not used; no action is taken.  Do you want to remove duplicates from the list?

Comment: Also, as an aside, here your `TFindDuplicates` method is a `procedure of object` but you are passing `FindDuplicates`, which is a regular method (ie: not `of object`) and is also not a procedure but a function.  One of the two would need to be changed for this to compile.

Comment: Reading this further, are you perhaps not looking for duplications in the list itself but are rather trying to find (search for) a list entry which corresponds to an object or other identifier aquired elsewhere?

Comment: i don't want to find duplicates in TObjectList i want to eliminate duplicates in 
my ImageList so i use TObjectList as a data structure that contain Icon(hicon) handle
if the icon always added to imaglist i won't add it again i just point to the index of it 
any way thank's for your patience for being cooperative...

Comment: As I can understand after reading sample code at *pastebin* your problem is to find duplicates in `TImageList`. You have file list, and each file has own icon (`HICON`). You are going to populate `TImageList` with these icons and get `ImageIndex` back. So if `ImageList` already has icon like your new file, then you want to use this existing `ImageIndex`, without adding new icon to `ImageList`. 
so. question is: Is this your problem or not. if so, ask about your exact problem. if no, then why did you paste patebin code here?

Comment: @teran this is exactly the situation

Comment: @S.FATEH ok, then I have one question and one suggestion. question: How many files do you have in list, does this overcomplicating worth it? suggestion: comparing binary icon data is expensive for this task. Another way is to get file type (mime-type), as you know all *jpeg* files have same icon, and so on, excluding `exe` and `lnk` files. So suggestion is - to popuplate Image list depending on file type, instead of binary icon data.

Comment: for your question number of files determined at run time can be from 1 to 10 to 100 
your suggestion really meet my needs I'll take your advice...but what about choosing the hard way :) pastebin code...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, as we found in comments, we have 2 tasks:

1. How to find if `TObjectList` already contains an item (so new item is an duplicate)
2. How to manage file icons in `TImageList` to reduce memory usage and store  only unique icons.

As I mentioned in comments, you should ask about your second question in separate thread, but I suggest you to add new files icons depeding on new file mime-type, instead of binary icon data. Here you have to create file-type dictionary, determine file-type and so on..

What about duplicates in `TObjectList`.
You probably know, that there is `generic` implemntation of `TObjectList` - `TObjectsList<T>`. As in your example you can define `TPersonList` as `TObjectList<TPerson>`, so `items` property always returns `TPerson` objects instance.

now, generic task with lists - list sorting. Take a look at `Sort()` method of `TObjectList<T>/TList`. It has 2 overload methods. One of them is default, and second takes an `Comparer` as parameter. Actually, the first method also uses an comparer - default comparer.
So comparer is an implemntation of `IComparer<T>` interface wich has the only method - `function Compare(l,r : T):integer`; Usually you  define this sort-comparer  at runtime as *anonimous method*, before calling the `Sort()` method. Using you anonimous method you always know how to compare two `T`-typed objects, and then you can determine wich of them is "greater" than other, and should be the first in list.

so the same situation you have while searching for duplicates in list. but now you have to determine, are 2 objects equal or not.

Let us suppose you have `personList : TPersonList` wich contains `TPerson` instances. Each person has, for exmaple, name, surname, date of birth and ID.
Of course default comparer knows nothing about how to compare 2 persons. But you can provide new comparer wich knows. For example, let suppose 2 objects are equals, if their IDs are equal;

```
    TPerson = class(TObject)
      strict private
        FName : string;
        FSurname : string;
        FDateOfBirth : TDateTime;
        FId : string;   {passport number or something else}
      public
        constructor Create(aID : string; aDoB : TDateTime);

        property Name : string read FName write FName;
        property Surname : string read FSurname write FSurname;
        property DateOfBirth : TDateTime read FDateOfBirth;
        property ID : string read FId;
    end;


    TPersonList = class(TObjectList<TPerson>)
      public
        constructor Create();
    end;
```

`TPerson` constructor is usual:

```
constructor TPerson.Create(aID: string; aDoB: TDateTime);
begin
    inherited Create();
    FID := aId;
    FDateOfBirth := aDoB;
end;
```

now we have to write `TPersonList` contructor. As you can see,`TObejctList` constructor has few overloads. One of them has `Comparer` parameter. It saves `aComparer` to `FComparer` field. Now, take a look at `Contains` method. It finds does list already contain object or not. It uses `IndexOf` method. So if returned index = 0 then list contains our object.

So now our task is to define new comparer in `TPersonList` constructor. We should define comparsion method, then create comparer object and pass it to List contructor.

```
constructor TPersonList.Create();
var comparer : IComparer<TPerson>;
    comparison : TComparison<TPerson>;
begin
    comparison := function(const l,r : TPerson):integer
                  begin
                    if l.ID = r.id then exit(0)
                    else if l.ID > r.ID then exit(-1)
                    else exit(1);
                  end;

    comparer := TComparer<TPerson>.Construct(comparison);

    inherited Create(comparer);
end;
```

to test our code, lets add some persons to list.

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var persons : TPersonList;

    function AddPerson(id : string; date : TDateTime):boolean;
    var p : TPerson;
    begin
        p := TPerson.Create(id, date);

        result := not persons.Contains(p);

        if result then
            persons.Add(p)
        else begin
            ShowMessage('list already contains person with id = ' + id);
            p.Free();
        end;
    end;
begin
    persons := TPersonList.Create();
    try
        AddPerson('1', StrToDate('01.01.2000'));
        AddPerson('2', StrToDate('01.01.2000'));
        AddPerson('3', StrToDate('01.01.2000'));
        AddPerson('2', StrToDate('01.01.2000')); // we will get message here.
    finally
        persons.Free();
    end;
end;
```

So, this is the usual way how to determine if `TList` (or its descendant) contains object.

Comment: after i was disappointed to find good solution i open stackoverflow to see new notification and thanks to god it's not a new comment but  an answer @teran thanks's and i hope this will help other programmers in such tasks.

Comment: +1 for putting in the effort here. However, @S.FATEH you should be aware that this does not answer the question you asked. That's not to say that it's not the information that you need. It is exactly that. But my point is that you asked the wrong question. We had to rely on the huge comment trail to work out what you really wanted. The lesson you can draw from this is that it pays to ask about problems rather than solutions, and that you should be prepared to put in time writing good questions. And often that means making significant edits to existing questions.